# Show that $m^4+4n^4$ can be expressed as the sum of four squares of natural numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Let $m,n$ be natural numbers and $m\not=n$. Show that $m^4+4n^4$ can
>   be expressed as the sum of four squares of natural numbers.

That is, express $m^4+4n^4$ as $A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2$ where $A,B,C,D$ is an expression in $n$ or/both $m$.

**@Tim: Yes, you are completely right. This is the most careless mistake ever!!** @Robert: And yes I want the sum of four squares of expressions (not necessarily polynomials, can contain the term mn) in m and/or n with integer coefficients.

And what is the significance of assuming $m\not=n?$

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Many many thanks!

Comment: Any positive integer can be expressed as the sum of four squares (Lagrange's four-square theorem).  But apparently you want something else: $m^4 + 4 n^4$ as the sum of four squares of polynomials in $m$ and $n$ with integer coefficients?

Comment: Your first question can be answered by saying that you made an error. You tried to apply the sum of cubes formula to a sum of squares!

Comment: @Tim: You are right, thanks. I don't what's in my mind... I have edited it.

Comment: $(m-m)^2+(n-n)^2+(m^2)^2+(2n^2)^2.$

Comment: Thanks John! Your answer is pretty striking, it didn't come up in my mind in the first place. But I guess it will work if we assume 0 as a natural number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$m^4+4n^4=(m^2)^2+(2n^2)^2=(m^2+2n^2)^2-(2mn)^2$$
$$=(m^2+2n^2-2mn)(m^2+2n^2+2mn)=\{(m-n)^2+n^2\}\{(m+n)^2+n^2\}$$

Now multiply

As $m\ne n, (m-n)^2>0$

Comment: Thanks! This should not be a difficult question. I should be more careful.

Comment: @user71346, my pleasure. Yes, nice to hear that "not difficult"